# Is there any way that one swatch is selected by default (magento configurable swatches)

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, addtocart, swatches, color-swatches

I am trying use Magento Configurable swatches in my website (for colors).

But I am facing some issues,

1. in Product details page, we have to select one color swatch.
2. In Product Listing Page, we are not able to add product to the cart (due to no color swatch is selected by default)
3. Is there any way that we can define independent prices for all color options? (currently the price of individual option is being
   added to the price of configurable/main product).